# Sometimes Toast doesn't disappear and remains visible even after I terminate App

Tags: android, android-toast

I have a very simple `Toast` shown under certain circumstamces:

```
if (!this.isFinishing()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.my_toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
]
```

Most of the times the `Toast` is shown and fades away as supposed but sometimes remains always visible and even if you terminate the App the `Toast` **doesn't disappear**.

This is a problem that occurs sporadically but when It happens It is very annoying and the only way to make the `Toast` fading away is rebooting the system or doing whatever thing that could show another `Toast`of whatever App.

This looks like a problem of Android itself rather than App since I have seen this issue happening on different devices and different Apps that use `Toast`.

I'm wondering if there is some workaround to prevent this issue.

Comment: never heard of this problem

Comment: What does the `!this.isFinishing()` stand for?

Comment: @Onik It's a check to make sure the current context passed to Toast constructor isn't finishing

Comment: Where are you calling this Toast from? Is it from an Activity?

Comment: @SammyT .....yes

Answer (score 0):

Toasts are meant to be system level notifications, so they won't disappear even if the app is killed. If you call `show` for several toasts they will show one after another. If the same toast is called multiple times, it'll give the impression that a toast will take a long time before fading away.

For app notifications, consider using `Snackbars` instead.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432339/android-snackbar-vs-toast-usage-and-difference).

Comment: Unfortunately isn't an impression. The Toast doesn't go away at all when this issue happens. I have checked Snackbar and maybe I'm missing something but seems It needs a layout view passed in the constructor so doesn't seems as lightweight as Toast.

Comment: @AndreaF - Is it possible that you are calling the toast `show` in a loop? About Snackbar being more demanding, that is true: you should specify its parent view properly.

Comment: there is no loop

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the Toast in an asynchronous call, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540416/persistent-toast-message-toast-wont-disappear-after-execution), Toasts can get stuck when called from a thread that finishes and is killed before the Toast has a chance to disappear.  If you're calling it in a separate thread, you may want to consider calling it from the main thread instead.